# A clean way to aggregate/groupby involving only the distinct values in each column?

Tags: r

I've been using the dplyr package to create aggregated data tables, for example using the following code:

```
agg_data <- df %>%
 select(calc.method, price1, price2) %>%
 group_by(calc.method) %>%
 summarize(
  count = n(),
  mean_price1 = round(mean(price1, na.rm = TRUE),2),
  mean_price2 = round(mean(price2, na.rm = TRUE),2))
```

However, I would like to only calculate the mean over the distinct values of price1 and price2 within groups

e.g:

Price1: 1 1 2 1 2 2 1

Goes to (before aggregation):

Price1: 1 2 1 2 1

(and these in general don't have the same numbers of after removal for price1 and price2). I would also like to calculate a count for each (price1 and price2), counting only distinct values within groups. (Groups are defined as two or more identical values adjacent to each other)

I have tried:

```
agg_data <- df %>%
 select(calc.method, price1, price2) %>%
 group_by(calc.method) %>%
 summarize(
  count = n(),
  mean_price1 = round(mean(distinct(price1), na.rm = TRUE),2),
  mean_price2 = round(mean(distinct(price2), na.rm = TRUE),2))
```

And also tried wrapping the columns within the select function with `distinct()`, but both these throw errors.

Is there a way to do this using dplyr or another similar package without having to write something from scratch?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Have you tried using `unique` instead of `distinct`?

Comment: I've actually realised that I don't want just distinct values of price1 and price2 but distict within groups, so something like:

price1: 1 1 2 1 2 2 1

Would go to (before aggregation):

price1: 1 2 1 2 1

Comment: Can we see some data? (Use `dput()` to provide a sample)

Comment: As mentioned in response to @aichao solution below, I've used the same concept but rle(price1)$values etc within summarize for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To satisfy your requirement for *distinct*, we need to remove successive values that are the same. For numeric vectors, this can be accomplished by:

```
x <- x[c(1, which(diff(x) != 0)+1)]
```

The default use of `diff` computes the difference between adjoining elements in the vector. We use this to detect successive values that are different, for which `diff(x) != 0`. Since the output differences are lagged by `1`, we add `1` to the indices of these *distinct* elements, and we also want the first element as distinct. For example:

```
x <- c(1,1,2,1,2,2,1)
x <- x[c(1, which(diff(x) != 0)+1)]
##[1] 1 2 1 2 1
```

We can then use this with `dplyr`:

```
agg_data <- df %>% group_by(calc.method) %>%
                   summarize(count = n(),
                             count_non_rep_1 = length(price1[c(1,which(diff(price1) != 0)+1)]),
                             mean_price1 = round(mean(price1[c(1,which(diff(price1) != 0)+1)], na.rm=TRUE),2),
                             count_non_rep_2 = length(price2[c(1,which(diff(price2) != 0)+1)]),
                             mean_price2 = round(mean(price2[c(1,which(diff(price2) != 0)+1)], na.rm=TRUE),2))
```

or, better yet, define the function:

```
remove.repeats <- function(x) {
  x[c(1,which(diff(x) != 0)+1)]
}
```

and use it with `dplyr`:

```
agg_data <- df %>% group_by(calc.method) %>%
                   summarize(count = n(),
                             count_non_rep_1 = length(remove.repeats(price1)),
                             mean_price1 = round(mean(remove.repeats(price1), na.rm=TRUE),2),
                             count_non_rep_2 = length(remove.repeats(price2)),                             
                             mean_price2 = round(mean(remove.repeats(price2), na.rm=TRUE),2))
```

Using this on some example data that is hopefully similar to yours:

```
df <- structure(list(calc.method = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
price1 = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3), 
price2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1)), 
.Names = c("calc.method", "price1", "price2"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
##   calc.method price1 price2
##1            A      1      1
##2            A      1      1
##3            A      2      1
##4            A      1      1
##5            A      2      1
##6            A      2      1
##7            A      1      1
##8            B      1      2
##9            B      1      1
##10           B      2      2
##11           B      2      1
##12           B      2      2
##13           B      2      1
##14           B      1      2
##15           B      3      1
```

We get:

```
print(agg_data)
### A tibble: 2 x 6
##  calc.method count count_non_rep_1 mean_price1 count_non_rep_2 mean_price2
##       <fctr> <int>           <int>       <dbl>           <int>       <dbl>
##1           A     7               5        1.40               1         1.0
##2           B     8               4        1.75               8         1.5
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I think using rle(price1)$values is cleaner though, but I've used the same concept.

Comment: @Sol: that is a better answer, you should actually post that!